# returns false for data value loadComplete jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

**EDITED** JS:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, 
    {
        mtype: "POST",
        viewRecords: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        sortable: false,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        rowList: [10,20,50],
        xmlReader: {
            root: "tasks",
            row: "task",
            repeatitems: false
        }
    });

<script>
        var subjects = <?php echo $Subject ?>;
        var users = <?php echo $trimmed ?>;
        var lastsel3;
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $grid = $("#assign"),
        initDateEdit = function (elem) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    showButtonPanel: true
                });
            }, 100);
            },
        initDateSearch = function (elem) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    showButtonPanel: true
                });
            }, 100);
            };
            $grid.jqGrid({
        url: 'assignedTasks.php',
        colNames: ["track","Assigned To","JobID","Subject","Notes","Details","Due Date","Submit Date", "AssignUser"],
        colModel: [ 
            {
                name: "track",
                index:"TrackID",
                key: true,
                align: "center",
                xmlmap:"TrackID",
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                name:"User",
                index:"UserID",
                align: "center",
                editable: true,
                xmlmap:"UserID",
                edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {value: users},
                editrules: {required: true},
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name: "JobID",
                index:"TaskID",
                xmlmap:"TaskID",
                editable: true,
                align:"center",
                editrules: {required: true},
                sortable: false,
            },
            {
                name: "Subject",
                index:"TaskSubject",
                align: "center",
                xmlmap:"TaskSubject",
                editable: true,
                edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {value: subjects},
                editrules: {required: true},
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name:"Notes",
                index:"Notes",
                align: "center",
                height: 20,
                xmlmap:"Notes",
                editable: true,
                edittype: 'textarea',
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name:"Details",
                index:"Details",
                align: "center",
                xmlmap: "Details",
                editable: false,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name:"DueDate",
                index:"DueDate",
                align: "center",
                editable: true,
                xmlmap:"DueDate",
                editrules:{required: true},
                editoptions: {dataInit: initDateEdit},
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {newformat: 'd-M-Y'},
                datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name:"Submitted",
                index:"Submitted",
                align: "center",
                xmlmap: "Submitted",
                editable: false,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                name:"AssignUser",
                index:"AssignUser",
                align: "center",
                xmlmap: "AssignUser",
                hidden:true,
                editable: false
            }
        ],
        loadComplete : function()
                        {   
                            var rows = $grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                            alert(rows);
                            for (ID in rows)
                            {
                                var data = $grid.getCell(ID,'Details');
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        },
        gridview: true,
        ondblClickRow: function(track){
                        if(track && track!==lastsel3)
                            {   
                                $('#assign').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel3); 
                                $('#assign').jqGrid('viewGridRow',track); 
                                lastsel3=track; 
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                $("#assign").jqGrid('viewGridRow',track);
                            }
                        },

        editurl: 'addTasks.php',
        pager: $('#assignNav'),
        caption: "Assign Tasks"
    }).navGrid('#assignNav',{edit:true,add:true,del:true},{},{},{},{multipleSearch: false, multipleGroup: false});
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        $("#assign").setGridWidth($(window).width()-"185");
        $("#assign").setGridHeight($(window).height()-"310");
    }).trigger('resize');
        });
    setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#assign').setGridParam({datatype: 'xml'}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{current:true}]);
        },60000);

    </script>
```

I am using this event to get the value inside the cell. When i run the code the alert returns "false" for the first couple of cells even though they have a value assigned and then returns the right value for all the corresponding ones. How do i fix this?
I tried gridComplete event and the result was the same.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tasks>
    <task>
        <TaskID>job0001</TaskID>
        <UserID>admin</UserID>
        <AssignID></AssignID>
        <AssignDate></AssignDate>
        <DueDate></DueDate>
        <AssignUser>1</AssignUser>
        <TaskSubject></TaskSubject>
        <Notes>Urgent!</Notes>
        <TrackID>1</TrackID>
        <Details>Not Started</Details>
        <Submitted></Submitted>
        <folderLink></folderLink>
    </task>
    <task>
        <TaskID>job00004</TaskID>
        <UserID>admin</UserID>
        <AssignID></AssignID>
        <AssignDate>2012-02-07</AssignDate>
        <DueDate>2012-02-16</DueDate>
        <AssignUser>1</AssignUser>
        <TaskSubject></TaskSubject>
        <Notes>ajsbaljb</Notes>
        <TrackID>7</TrackID>
        <Details>Not Started</Details>
        <Submitted></Submitted>
        <folderLink></folderLink>
    </task>
</tasks>
```

**EDIT 2**: If I do this

```
loadComplete : function()
                        {

                            var data = $grid.getCol('Details');
                            alert(data);
                        },
```

it returns everything correctly!

Comment: You should include the full JavaScript code which uses jqGrid and include the testdata (JSON or XML) so that the problem which you described can be reproduced.

Comment: @Oleg updated the post, what I am really trying to do is change row color according to content in the cell but I cant get past this point because of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loadComplete : function()
                    {
                        var data = $grid.getCol('Details', true);
                    },
```

This returns exactly what I had in the Details Cell with the rowIds. This solved where I was stuck but I would still like to know why the other function returned false.